# Enzyme with chutzpah and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enzyme, chutzpah

I am trying to write react app test using Enzyme and chutzpah. tests would be in typescript and using chutzpah to run them. I am consuming npm package [@types/enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/enzyme) and [enzyme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme) to write tests. This is how i am writing in my tests

```
import * as enzyme from "Package/Scripts/3rdParty/index";
...
const ddd = enzyme.shallow(component);
```

however when I ran test it fails with this error "Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports"

In index.js file which comes with enzyme has following code and failure happen in the first line.

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.ReactWrapper = exports.ShallowWrapper = exports.mount = exports.shallow = exports.render = undefined;
var _ReactWrapper = require('./ReactWrapper');
...
```

If I put index.js code inside the following line of code then it doesn't complain the same issue

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
});
```

However enzyme has many js module and i don't want to do everywhere same thing. Any idea how can I fix this without modifying anything on the enzyme js files. Appreciate any help on this.